# Sans-Serif font suggestions for small (11pt), bold, uppercase heading text

Tags: fonts, wpf

I need some suggestions for a sans-serif font to use as a Heading/Label. I'm looking at small 11pt text, which is all uppercase and bold.

I'm writing my app using WPF on Windows XP and none of the fonts I've chosen so far look slick/smooth.

I've tried Gill Sans MT and Franklin Gothic Demi Cond so far.

Comment: If you're developing a Windows app, why not just go with the default - i.e. whatver the current system font setting is - for consistency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verdana always looked pretty good to me when small, bold and uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Verdana vs. DejaVu Sans]

**Verdana** (nominated by Scott Brown) is indeed very readable at small sizes, but a small percentage of computers don't have it installed. **DejaVu Sans** (see above) is a suitable fallback. My suggestion for a complete **Verdana-like font stack** is

> `Verdana, "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "DejaVu LGC Sans", Geneva, sans-serif;`

I give my reasons in "[**Three font stacks to match DejaVu / Bitstream Vera**](http://www.grputland.com/2012/09/three-font-stacks-to-match-dejavu.html)".

Answer (score 0):

For screen display "lucida grande" is a good choice (facebook use it on small text).
(But this is not available on iPad.)

Answer (score -1):

from my point of view..

1.times new roman

2.calibri

3.candara

4.Century gothic

5.Felix titling

and if you want to check your font online check this

This link will solve your problem for sure.. :)

http://www.typetester.org/

and btw 11 pt is equal to 0.938em...

hope it will work for you..

Comment: 'em's are relative to whatever you, and the browser user, has set the base at. You can't say that 11pt = anything em.

Comment: correct. An em is essentially a percentage measurement which was based upon the proportions of a capital M. Nowadays it is simply the point size expressed as one unit and only has meaning in the context of the currently specified point size (so 11pt=.938em is like saying 11pt=.938percent, which forces one to ask "of what?")

Comment: And I don't think WPF supports ems anyway.

Comment: How is Times New Roman Sans-Serif?